dompdf inline-block overlap previous elements
I have a simple HTML-structure and put it to dompdf to render a PDF file. When i have 2 columns (div) with display:inline-block and a width that both can stay together, both columns move upwards and overlap my headlines.
I test it with no css properties and the problem is still there.
HTML:
<div class="page" style="width:100%;">
    <h1>1. Headline one</h1>
    <h2>second subline</h2>
    <br>
    <div style="display:inline-block;margin-right:3%;width:47.5%;">
        <p style="display:block;margin-top:23px;margin-bottom:23px;">some text with no sense but very long. some text with no sense but very long. some text with no sense but very long.
         some text with no sense but very long. some text with no sense but very long. some text with no sense but very long. 
         some text with no sense but very long. some text with no sense but very long. some text with no sense but very long. 
         some text with no sense but very long. some text with no sense but very long. some text with no sense but very long. 
         some text with no sense but very long. some text with no sense but very long. some text with no sense but very long. 
         some text with no sense but very long. some text with no sense but very long. some text with no sense but very long. 
         some text with no sense but very long. some text with no sense but very long. some text with no sense but very long. 
         some text with no sense but very long. some text with no sense but very long. some text with no sense but very long. 
         some text with no sense but very long. some text with no sense but very long. some text with no sense but very long. 
         some text with no sense but very long. some text with no sense but very long. some text with no sense but very long. 
         some text with no sense but very long. some text with no sense but very long. some text with no sense but very long. </p>
    </div>
    <div style="display:inline-block;margin-right:0%;width:47.5%;">
        <p style="display:block;margin-top:23px;margin-bottom:23px;">some text</p>
    </div>
    <div style="page-break-before:always;"></div>
    <div style="display:inline-block;margin-right:0%;width:47.5%;">
        <p style="display:block;margin-top:23px;margin-bottom:23px;">some text with no sense but very long. some text with no sense but very long. some text with no sense but very long.
        some text with no sense but very long. some text with no sense but very long. some text with no sense but very long. 
        some text with no sense but very long. some text with no sense but very long. some text with no sense but very long. 
        some text with no sense but very long. some text with no sense but very long. some text with no sense but very long. 
        some text with no sense but very long. some text with no sense but very long. some text with no sense but very long. 
        some text with no sense but very long. some text with no sense but very long. some text with no sense but very long. 
        some text with no sense but very long. some text with no sense but very long. some text with no sense but very long. 
        some text with no sense but very long. some text with no sense but very long. some text with no sense but very long. 
        some text with no sense but very long. some text with no sense but very long. some text with no sense but very long. 
        some text with no sense but very long. some text with no sense but very long. some text with no sense but very long. 
        some text with no sense but very long. some text with no sense but very long. some text with no sense but very long. </p>
    </div>
    <div style="display:inline-block;margin-right:0%;width:47.5%;">
        <p style="display:block;margin-top:23px;margin-bottom:23px;">some text</p>
    </div>
    <div style="display:inline-block;margin-right:0%;width:47.5%;">
        <br>more text
    </div>
</div>

PHP:
$dompdf = new Dompdf();
    $options = $dompdf->getOptions();
    $dompdf->getFontMetrics()->registerFont(
        ['family' => 'AdelleSans', 'style' => 'normal', 'weight' => '400'],
        $fontDirectory . 'AdelleSans.ttf'
    );
    $dompdf->getFontMetrics()->registerFont(
        ['family' => 'AdelleSans', 'style' => 'normal', 'weight' => '600'],
        $fontDirectory . 'AdelleSansBold.ttf'
    );
    $options->set('defaultFont', 'AdelleSans');
    $options->set('isHtml5ParserEnabled', true);

    $dompdf->loadHtml($html,'UTF-8');
    $dompdf->setPaper('A4', 'landscape');
    $dompdf->set_option('dpi',300);
    $dompdf->set_option('isRemoteEnabled', true);
    $dompdf->set_option('defaultMediaType', 'all');
    $dompdf->set_option('isFontSubsettingEnabled', true);
    $dompdf->render();
    $output = $dompdf->output();
    file_put_contents("test.pdf", $output);
    $dompdf->stream("test.pdf", array("Attachment" => false));

My goal is to view both columns side by side but on the current y-state with no overlap of previous elements.

We are a lazy bunch. The only way to see what the PDF looks like would be to actually run your code. Not many people will take that effort for you, without having an idea of the real problem. Can you post an image of the PDF as you get it? The whole PDF please, not just the problem spot, so if there are multiple pages, show that too.

Well, since you didn't respond I did actually run your code, obviously without the fonts, and I can confirm that the texts is shown too high, overlapping the headlines. Tried some basic things to solve this, but I must admit that it looks like a bug. Perhaps rewriting it as an old-fashioned <table>......</table> will work? Otherwise opening an issue on Github might get you an answer.
